# Parent overflow hidden with absolute children

Tags: css

Scenario: I need a container with relative positioning, which has 2 absolute positioned children. On clicking the container both children will be transitioned on transform property, one being moved to the left and one being moved to the right, both outside the window, so I need somehow to set `overflow: hidden` on the parent, ***in order not to show the transitioned elements outside of parent container***.

The thing is parent does not have a height set because of the absolute children, and when I use `overflow-x: hidden` on it, nothing is showed anymore.

Is it possible to set an overflow so that when children gets transformed to left/right no scrollbar will be showed? I do not want to set overflow on the body element. I'm looking for **CSS-only** solutions, if there are any.

Also setting a fixed height for parent is not a solution to my problem, please take that into consideration.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FullScreen-Split | Experimental</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box clearfix">
            <div class="half-left">
                <div class="split">
                    <div class="details">
                        <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
                        <h3>Porsche Dealer Auto</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="half-right">
                <div class="split">
                    <div class="details">
                        <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
                        <h3>Porsche Dealer Auto</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my SASS code

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    &.active {
        .half-left {
            transform: translateX(-150%);
        }

        .half-right {
            transform: translateX(150%);
        }
    }

    .half-left,
    .half-right {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 25px 0;
        transition: 2s transform ease-out;
        background-color: #3a3a3a;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .half-left {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        > .split {
            width: 200%;
        }
    }

    .half-right {
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;

        > .split {
            margin-left: -50%;
        }
    }

    .split {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .details {
        text-align: center;

        > i.fa {
            font-size: 62px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }

        > h3 {
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;

    &::before,
    &::after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

`html` and `body` elements are set to `width: 100%` and `height: 100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of positioning `half-left` and `half-right` as `absolute`, you could just float them both left and add `overflow: hidden` to the parent container.

```
.half-left, half-right {
    float: left;
}

.box {
    position: relaitve;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then when you add `active` to the parent container, the two children should transform as you intended.

Here's a Codepen to demonstrate : - https://codepen.io/aphextwix/pen/KmmgXJ

Comment: Uh, I didn't think of that. Thank you for your help! But, just out of curiosity, is there any possibility to use my code with absolute positioning and make it work? Just a curiosity. Is CSS limited in this case or is there some work-around on absolute children?

Comment: You'd have to set a fixed height on the parent in order for it to work with absolute positioning on the child elements.

Comment: I know, but besides that, is there any other solution?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. By positioning the child elements `absolute` you're taking them out of the document flow. The parent has no reference to their height and thus does not expand accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to not use `position: absolute` or `float`, as neither is meant for general layout.

They both take their element out flow (in somewhat different ways though), and make it more difficult to create a responsive page.

You could simplify the code a little and use `display: inline-block`, like this

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
}
.box .half {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  transition: 2s transform ease-out;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}
.box .details {
  text-align: center;
}
.box .details > i.fa {
  font-size: 62px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.box .details > h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="half">
      <div class="details">
        <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
        <h3>Porsche Dealer Auto</h3>
      </div>
    </div><!-- this comment remove the white space between the inline-block elements
 --><div class="half">
      <div class="details">
        <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
        <h3>Porsche Dealer Auto</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

---

Or use `flexbox`, which today is the recommended way to do layout

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.box .half {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  transition: 2s transform ease-out;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}
.box .details {
  text-align: center;
}
.box .details > i.fa {
  font-size: 62px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.box .details > h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="half">
      <div class="details">
        <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
        <h3>Porsche Dealer Auto</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <div class="details">
        <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
        <h3>Porsche Dealer Auto</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I do not like the inline-block solution, altough the flex one is good. The thing is, here, I don't see any major advantage in using flexbox instead of positioning... that's why I didn't use flexbox in the first place, I thought abs positioning suits better.